# Can't install Google mobile ads SDK by pod install. Cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods, google-mobile-ads

I want to install google mobile ads SDK by pod install but it doesn't install. It gives this error:

```
LoadError - linked to incompatible /Users/dipanshukashyap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/libruby.3.2.dylib - /Users/dipanshukashyap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle
<internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
<internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
/Users/dipanshukashyap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/dipanshukashyap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
<internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
/Users/dipanshukashyap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
<internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/typhoeus-1.4.1/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
<internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:284:in `ensure_versions_file_loaded'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:208:in `search'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `block in search'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `select'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `search'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:416:in `create_set_from_sources'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:385:in `find_cached_set'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:360:in `specifications_for_dependency'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165:in `search_for'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `each'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_dependencies'
/Users/dipanshukashyap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:60:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Users/dipanshukashyap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:77:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
/Users/dipanshukashyap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:59:in `sort_dependencies'
/Users/dipanshukashyap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:754:in `push_state_for_requirements'
/Users/dipanshukashyap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:288:in `push_initial_state'
/Users/dipanshukashyap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:210:in `start_resolution'
/Users/dipanshukashyap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:168:in `resolve'
/Users/dipanshukashyap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1082:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1080:in `resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:125:in `analyze'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/dipanshukashyap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```

I tried running both "pod install" and "pod install --repo-update" but the error is same.
I tried to install other pod dependency and they install correctly, error only comes in installing 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'.

Here is my pod env:

```
   CocoaPods : 1.14.3
        Ruby : ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [arm64-darwin23]
    RubyGems : 3.4.10
        Host : macOS 14.2 (23C64)
       Xcode : 15.1 (15C65)
         Git : git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-145)
Ruby lib dir : /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

Here is my pod file:

```
platform :ios, '17.0'

target 'MyProject' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyProject
  pod 'GeoFire'
  pod 'FirebaseAuth'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'GoogleSignInSwiftSupport'
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'

end
```

I tried to install using cloudflare VPN and mobile data but neither of them works.

Comment: 兄弟，你需要VPN，然后用http命令行代理，之后再进行pod install